# Collocations vs compound nouns

Tags: compounds, collocations

Is there any definable difference between collocations and compound nouns? Or is it just frequency?

The answer does not seem to be transparency vs idiomaticity - looking at the text I'm presenting to my students tomorrow, *sunlight* looks like a compound noun but its meaning is completely predictable, whereas my intuition and textbook say *primary consumers* (in a food chain) is a collocation, but it's a technical term so the meaning is not predictable in isolation. And how about *carbon dioxide*?

Edit: this is helpful:

"Compounds include word pairs that occur consecutively in language and typically are immutable in function. Noun-noun pairs are one such example, which not only occur consecutively but also function as a constituent. Cowie [8] notes that compounds form a bridge between collocations and idioms,
since, like collocations, they are quite invariable, but they are not necessarily semantically opaque." McKeown, K.R. and Radev, D.R., 2000. Collocations. Handbook of Natural Language Processing. Marcel Dekker, pp.1-23.

And this: Bauer, L. (1998). When is a sequence of two nouns a compound in English? English Language and Linguistics, 2(1), 65-86. doi:10.1017/S1360674300000691

Comment: There's certainly a difference between compound nouns and syntactic constructions. Items like "greenhouse" and "cotton-plant" are morphological compounds, single words, whereas "green house" and "cotton shirt" are syntactic constructions consisting of separate words.

Comment: There are syntactic tests for establishing compound vs syntactic construction status. For example, in your "primary consumers" example, the component parts can enter into relations of coordination and modification, e,g, "primary and secondary consumers" but compounds like, say, "ice-cream" do not submit to this manipulation, cf. the ungrammatical *"ice- and custard- creams".

Comment: What about French teacher (nationality) versus French teacher (occupation)? Both of those seem to be productive but only the first can be coordinated.

Comment: There's no doubt that these are syntactic constructions. not compounds. "French" (nationality) is an adjective modifying "teacher", and "French" (occupation) is a complement of "teacher".

Comment: That's what I thought. But my point is that the first one can be syntactically manipulated whereas the second cannot - *a French teacher and a German one (meaning occupation) - so your test would falsely distinguish it as a compound.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. We can say that someone is a "French and history teacher", meaning they teach two subjects.

Comment: True. But I don't think "The school recruited a French teacher and a German one" can have the occupation interpretation; on the other hand, we can say "The school recruited a good French teacher and a bad one" under that interpretation.

Comment: I'd say it **can** have that interpretation in the right context. Also we can have "The school recruited French and German teachers", where "French" could either be a nationality or the subject being taught. Importantly. I don't think anyone would consider "French teacher" a compound noun irrespective of the interpretation of "French".